# Why $L_X \circ d = d \circ L_X$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

How to understand that the Lie derivative $L_X$ commutes with exterior differentiation $d$?

I can follow the proof step by step, but I do not think I understand it.

A similar question concerns $F^* \circ d = d \circ F^*$, namely, the pull-back commutes with exterior differentiation.

There should be some simple reason for two things to commute, right?

Comment: If you believe the latter, you get the former for free: $L_X Y$ is (maybe I am off by a sign) the derivative at $t=0$ of $\phi^t_*(Y)$ where $\phi^t$ is the flow generated by $X$. Here we assume the vector field is complete, but you are asking about a local property, so we may as well cut off the vector field outside of a compact neighborhood, so this is fine. Then differentiating your second formula at $t=0$ gives you the first formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out! It is so smart.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, let $F:M\to N$ be a smooth map, and let $\omega \in \Omega^k(N)$ be a smooth $k$ form on $N$.

Then for each $p\in M$ and $v_1,\dots,v_k \in T_pM$ we have $(F^*\omega)_p(v_1,\dots,v_k):=w_{F(p)}(dF_p(v_1),\dots,dF_p(v_k))$.

If $(V,\psi=(y^j))$ is a chart on $N$, then $\omega_{|V}=\sum'_Jw_J \;dy^{j1}\wedge\dots\wedge dy^{j_k}$.

Then $(F^*\omega)_{|F^{-1}(V)}=\sum'_J (w_J\circ F) \;d(y^{j1}\circ F)\wedge\dots\wedge d(y^{j_k}\circ F)$

While $(dw)_{|V}=\sum'_J dw_J \wedge dy^{j1}\wedge\dots\wedge dy^{j_k}$

And $[d(F^*\omega)]_{|F^{-1}(V)}=\sum'_J d(w_J\circ F) \wedge d(y^{j1}\circ F)\wedge\dots\wedge d(y^{j_k}\circ F)$

And $[F^*(dw)]_{|F^{-1}(V)}=\sum'_J d(w_J\circ F) \wedge d(y^{j1}\circ F)\wedge\dots\wedge d(y^{j_k}\circ F)$

Answer (score 3):

If $f(t)^\ast \alpha = b_I(x,t)dx_I$, then
\begin{align*} dL_X\alpha &=d\frac{d}{dt} f^\ast\alpha\\
&= d (b_I)_tdx_I = (b_I)_{tx_i}dx_i\wedge dx_I
\\&=
\frac{d}{dt} d(b_Idx_I) = \frac{d}{dt} d f^\ast\alpha
=\frac{d}{dt} f^\ast d\alpha
\\&= L_Xd\alpha\end{align*}